# Reachability of IP address of virtual machine

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, tcp-ip

I have a virtual machine (Linux) installed in my PC (Windows) and I was wondering the reachability of the IP address assigned to the virtual machine.

According to `ipconfig` on Windows and `ifconfig` on Linux:

for the **host machine**:

- IP address is 192.168.1.208
- subnet masking is 255.255.255.0

for the **virtual machine**:

- IP address is 192.168.124.130
- subnet masking is 255.255.255.0

I was wondering how to make the virtual machine a part of the LAN so that other devices on the LAN can access it.

Update:
The issue is resolved after I changed the VM network adapter to **Bridged**.

Comment: what's the output of `ip route`

Comment: Look at `Bridged Adapter` and `Host Only Adapter`.

Comment: sorry, I meant on the host machine too

Comment: Do you want to reach the VM from other machines on your LAN,? If so, do your want out forwarding on the host or would you prefer to give the VM a full 192 168.1.x/24 address so that it's directly part of the LAN network? Or are you asking how the host with an address 192.168.1.x can reach the VM with an address of 192.168.124.y?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/732041/edit) to respond. Do not reply here in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering how to make the virtual machine a part of the LAN

You need to use a bridged connection. This will be explained as one of the standard network configurations for whatever visualisation system you're using

Comment: This seems necessary, but not sufficient.  Won't the other hosts on the `192.168.1.0/24` LAN also need a static route so they know where traffic for `192.168.124.130` should be sent?

Comment: No. If you use a bridged connection your VM will get a 192.168.1.x/24 address just like every other system on your LAN